# How could I load my pages dynamically without reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a simple html/css webpage: [www.eveo.org](http://www.eveo.org)

All my content is located in my "content" div, 400px tall, and 960px wide. How could I update my content into that div without actually refreshing the web-page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding onto the jQuery aspect, here's an example where I do that very thing.

I have on my page a link which opens a container which is absolutely positioned where you clicked with your mouse, in this container is the contents of the link you clicked on. There's a lot more code than What I'm showing here which performs my specific task, but this should be abstracted enough for you to use.

Live Demo: http://wecodesign.com/demos/stackoverflow-7071545.htm

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateContainer( url ) {
    dynamicCon = '#dynamicContainer';    
    ObjTag = $( dynamicCon );
    ObjTag.load( url );
}
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( 'a[rel="dynamicLoad"]' ).bind( "click", function( event ) {
        url = $( this ).attr( 'href' );
        updateContainer( url );
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
</script>

<ul>
    <li><a href="stackoverflow-7071545-1.htm" rel="dynamicLoad">Page 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="stackoverflow-7071545-2.htm" rel="dynamicLoad">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="stackoverflow-7071545-3.htm">Page 3 (Will not dynamic load)</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="dynamicContainer"></div>
```

In case you're not familiar with jQuery, I'll explain a few things

- jQuery is a library that makes developing JavaScript apps a lot easier, and it's tested cross-browser, I've included Google's publicly available version so I don't have to host it, This will make the page load faster because users most likely have this Google version cached.
- In my `updateContainer()` function, I specify the container using [jQuery selector syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), then I put it into a jQuery tag `$()` so it becomes an object that I can then manipulate. I then use load to dynamically update it with the url that was passed to the function.
- `$(document).ready(function() {} );` is a pretty universally used thing in jQuery, it basically says, run what's in the curly braces when the document is [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).
- I put a rel="dynamicLoad" on the anchor tags I want to affect, I do this because you may not want all links to load dynamically into this container. what the selector `a[rel="dynamicLoad"]` does is finds all anchor tags with this rel tag attribute and modifies them with the code I specify.
- I grab the url and send it to the `updateContainer()` function, then I run `event.preventDefault()` and `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the link from doing what it normally does by default, which is to open the page, you'll notice that I passed "event" into the function call.

Comment: Will this method affect google analytics? Will analytics detect this method as a page load? I fear this will increase the bounce rate in my website. Is there any alternative solution to make some content of the page static and some dynamic without increasing the bounce rate and also by letting analytics to detect it as the page load?

Comment: please answer me here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495253/bind-inner-links-on-a-webpage-to-load-dynamically-without-increasing-the-analyti

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 1):

if you can live with a dependency on jQuery it's [quite easy](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Will this method affect google analytics? Will analytics detect this method as a page load? I fear this will increase the bounce rate in my website. Is there any alternative solution to make some content of the page static and some dynamic without increasing the bounce rate and also by letting analytics to detect it as the page load?

Comment: please answer me here..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495253/bind-inner-links-on-a-webpage-to-load-dynamically-without-increasing-the-analyti